# Unwanted new lines in Jekyll html templating

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid, templating

Here is an example of my Jekyll templating

```
{% for collection in site.collections %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            {{ collection[0] | capitalize }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And the (unwanted) result in html :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Css
    </div>
</div>
```

While I want this :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Css</div>
</div>
```

As you can see the generated html keeps the source formatting as if it was written in a `<pre>` tag. While the enduser sees the same thing, I think it's still badly written html.

Any way to correct this without removing the indentation in the source html ?

Comment: Here is a pull request from a user for a spaceless liquid tag. Maybe you can take a look and implement it if you can. https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/pull/607

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the line breaks and spaces in your Jekyll template - Jekyll just leaves them as-is.

The middle part of your template looks like this now:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        {{ collection[0] | capitalize }}
    </div>
</div>
```

...so the line breaks and spaces before and after the `{{ collection[0] ...` part will go into the generated HTML unchanged, so that it looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Css
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Solution:

Remove the line breaks between the `div` and the `{{ collection[0] ...` part:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{ collection[0] | capitalize }}</div>
</div>
```

...and you'll get the desired result:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Css</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but I know that. What I want is keeping my indentation as it is, but without rendering that indentation in the production file. I don't know if that's possible though

Comment: I *think* it's not possible, but I admit I'm not 100% sure. When I had special cases like this, I always removed the indentation in the template.